# C# code for Insert data to a table with ReferenceKey using Entity Mode

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-4, entity

can anyone tell me how to insert data to

```
Table Student has columns {stuId Name Age}
Table School has columns {classId Year sName}
```

"`sName`" is a reference key from Student Table

I want to insert data using Entity Model C#

Comment: your database design doesn't look good. you have "sName" in "School" table?

Comment: Are you saying `sName` is linked to `Name` from `Student`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                String SchooID = getNewID();
                Schools schl = new Schools();
                schl.school_reference = SchooID;
                schl.school_name = "Ananda Collage";

                schl.StudentReference.Value = cecbContext.Students.First(i => i.stud_name == "Josh");


                cecbContext.AddToSchools(schl);
                cecbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I found the answer in this way. this worked to me successfully. Thanks a lot for  your help  guys

Answer (score 0):

Try this to add student:

```
Student student = new Student(){studId="", Name="", Age=""};
myEntities.Students.AddObject(student);
myEntities.SaveChanges();
```

Adding school:

```
School school = new School(){classId="", Year = year, sName=""};
myEntities.Schools.AddObject(school);
myEntities.SaveChanges();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: actually i need to add data to school table? which has a reference from Student Table?